# how do I generate po file from php array?

Tags: localization, translation, poedit, po, mo

I've a php language file, that lists values in an array.

I want to transform this into .po file.

php file looks like this:

```
<?php 

$LANG_ = array(

// advanced search buttons
"_search1"              => "Start Search",
"_search2"              => "Hide Search Box",
"_search3"              => "Search",

// page numbering
"_pn1"              => "Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of %TOTAL_PAGES%",
"_pn2"              => "<< First",
"_pn3"              => "Last >>",

// _tpl_article-add.php
"_tpl_article-add1"             => "Article Submission Form",
"_tpl_article-add2"             => "Submit Article",
"_tpl_article-add3"             => "Article Submitted Successfully",


// errors
"_err14"            => "Delete",
"_err144"           => "Display Image",
"_err15"            => "Edit",
"_err16"            => "View",

);
?>
```

This is just an example, file itself is huge, over 3000 lines. It would kill me to insert every single one of these into a po catalog manually. Is there something that can automate this for me?

I'm using poedit.

Thanks, I'm new to this, so any insight will be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first entry is the file header, look into an existing *gettext* file (-po) what is needed. The escaping I did with `addslashes`; maybe you need to do more.

```
$fh = fopen("en.po", 'w');
fwrite($fh, "#\n");
fwrite($fh, "msgid \"\"\n");
fwrite($fh,  "msgstr \"\"\n");

foreach ($LANG_ as $key => $value) {
    $key = addslashes($key);
    $value = addslashes($value);
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
    fwrite($fh, "msgid \"$key\"\n");
    fwrite($fh, "msgstr \"$value\"\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: hm, that looks like an awesome solution... oh if I could understand that much php :)))

anyhow, I put it together with my array in one php file, and I got syntax error. Something about fclose...

Comment: I did not test the code, but `fclose($fh);` looks correct. Maybe missing newline thereafter.

Comment: I found it, it was fwrite($fh, "msgstr=\"$value\"\n); missing " after n. I will test it now and report :)

Comment: hm, the file I get the en.po seems empty :( I mean when I open it with poedit there is nothing inside, how is this possible? But when i view it with normal text editor lines are there... hm :) u helped me allot already.

Comment: I wrote an equal sign after msgid and msgstr that should have been blanks. Will edit answer

Answer (score 4):

Try [php2po](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/php2po.html) which will convert a PHP array into PO files and will also make sure that all of your escaping is correct. The PO file can then be edited in a tool like Poedit or [Virtaal](http://virtaal.org).